# Nominatim Openstreet map search based on Canada Postal Code

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap, postal-code, nominatim

I have installed Nominatim in my ubuntu 12.0.4 OS. I have downloaded North America- Canada osm map data from http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/canada.html url and installed in postgresql.

Now the problem is that I have searched 3485 postalcodes in my nominatim site but only 72 postal codes founded.

I want to know Why nominatim Postal Code search is not working? or any other osm data need to install for Postal Codes searching?

Or How can I search on nominatim based on Postal code?

Any suggestion related to search based on Canada postal codes is helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does OSM's nominatim instance return more postcode results? It uses some additional external resources for address lookups, for example TIGER for North America. As long as you haven't imported this data for you instance you will find less results than OSM's instance.

Keep in mind that addresses in OSM are far from being complete and the address coverage varies from country to country. Moreover, Nominatim has still some problems with postcodes in general.

Comment: It is not returning any response for that postal codes.

Comment: Is there any osm database that will work for canada postal codes?

Comment: There is just one OSM database. You can try to find an external data source for post codes which you can import into your Nominatim database, similar to TIGER. Otherwise you will probably have to use a different geocoder until OSM's postcode coverage increases.

Answer (score 0):

There's no free, definitive source of postal codes, as Canada Post maintains that it's a copyrighted product. [geocoder.ca](https://geocoder.ca/) no longer supplies updates to its free-to-use postal code list, perhaps in response to the [settlement](https://gogeomatics.ca/postal-codes-canada-post-backs-down-on-crowdsourced-open-data/) of Canada Post's lawsuit against them.

Geocoder's last update to the free-to-use list is from late 2015, and can be downloaded [here](http://geocoder.ca/onetimedownload/Canada.csv.gz) (gzipped CSV).